# Python weka wrapper: classify instances from another file

Tags: python-2.7, wrapper, weka

I'm using `Ubuntu 15.10`, `Python 2.7`, and have the current install of the `python weka-wrapper` package.

I'm doing the following: **(1)** Training a classifier based on data I load from a `.csv` file. **(2)** Loading a second set of data from another `.csv` file -- this data has the same header that designates features as was used to train the original classifier. **(3)** I'm attempting to use the trained classifier to  classify the data loaded from this second file -- what I really want, actually, is the probability of each instance conforming to a certain class (but that is an aside I will point out shortly)

Here is my code that takes the trained classifier and (second) file name as input:

```
 def classifyData(classifier,datFile):

    loader = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.CSVLoader")
    data = loader.load_file(datFile)
    data.class_is_last()

    preds = []
    dists = []

    iCount = 0
    for inst in data:
           iCount+=1
           pred = classifier.classify_instance(inst)
           dist = classifier.distribution_for_instance(inst)
           preds.append(pred)
           dists.append(dists)

    return preds,dists
```

**Note:** I should also note that the class variable (the last feature in the second data file) is designated with "?", representing data for which I do not have a label.

**Quick aside question:** Does the `dist` variable contain the probability of the class?  If not, how would I get this information?

Running this function produces the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging.distributionForInstance(Bagging.java:816)
at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.classifyInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:173)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "parsFunc.py", line 33, in main
initProb = classifyData(classifTrain,ttDir+"temp.csv")
 File "parsFunc.py", line 136, in classifyData
pred = classifier.classify_instance(inst)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/weka/classifiers.py", line 105, in classify_instance
return self.__classify(inst.jobject)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/javabridge/jutil.py", line 852, in fn
raise JavaException(x)
 javabridge.jutil.JavaException: 1
```

Not exactly what's going wrong here. I know there are the same number of instances in the second file as was used to train the model and that the header is the same.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javabridge.jutil.JavaException: 1` is not very helpful, I know, but it points to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Weka requires training and test sets (or data that you want to make predictions for) to have the **exact** same format, not only enforcing the order of the attributes, but also the order of the labels (in case of nominal attributes). The latter is necessary, since Weka stores label indices internally as a number and therefore the internal representation of a label, e.g., 1, has a different meaning in case of labels `{yes,no}` as opposed to `{no,yes}`.

When using CSV files, the amount of labels and/or the order of labels cannot be ensured, as the `CSVLoader` uses whatever strings it encounters as labels.
In your case, you don't have any labels in your class attribute column (they're all denoted as missing), which most likely results in that exception that you encountered.

What to do? Use [ARFF](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF) files instead of CSV files, as they have a header which defines the attributes (and the labels in case of nominal ones). By storing the header of the training set on disk, you can then re-use that to create your test set with the correct structure.

**Quick aside answer:** Yes, `dist` contains the class probabilities, aligned with the class labels.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I'm wondering: is there a way to specify the arff file header output -- i.e., specify the names of the two classes in the header and then write an arff file containing these test instances? My code is more of a 'real world' setting in which new instances are produced on the fly, written to a file, this file is loaded, and the instances are classified using a previously learned classifier.  I suppose I could manually write code to create this header if need be... or copy it from the training arff file opened as a txt file...

Comment: I have implemented code that writes out my data to an arff file, using the header of the training arff file -- this is absolutely the way to go as my code is now working. Thank you for your suggestion.  If you update your answer to suggest using the header of the training arff file to create a the testing arff file I will accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly. Also answered your *quick aside question*.

Comment: Thanks much! Accepted.